# How to view an active view C# class in 'Solution Explorer'?

Tags: visual-studio, solution-explorer

I have a solution which has many projects inside it.
I build the solution and have some compile errors.
Double clicking an error will open a class file, called FileA.cs.
What I don't know how to do is viewing FileA.cs in the Solution Explorer pane.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 2 options without macros, either always enable tracking, or bind a key to toggle it:

If you want to always enable tracking: Enable the [Track Active Item in Solution Explorer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8919d7f2(VS.80).aspx) option, but note there's some performance penalty is leaving this on.  Get to this by **Tools** > **Options** > **Projects and Solutions** > **General**

Alternatively, [bind a key to turn this on and off](http://www.paraesthesia.com/archive/2009/08/12/select-current-item-in-visual-studio-solution-explorer.aspx) (but you'll have to hit it twice).

Third, macro option, make this macro and bind to a key so you don't have to hit it twice to disable it:

```
Sub FindInSolutionExplorer()
 DTE.ExecuteCommand ("View.TrackActivityinSolutionExplorer")
 DTE.ExecuteCommand ("View.TrackActivityinSolutionExplorer")
End Sub
```

Comment: Why do we need to do it twice?

Comment: @Nam Gi VU - Just to turn it back off if you don't want the performance penalty.  If the performance isn't bad for you, you can just leave it on.